# how to load default namespace in external class in laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel-4

I added external namespace in Laravel 4.2 name `MyClasses` so when i try to use any default functionality of Laravel in that class. To fix the error i have to include that class first using `use` statement before class.

IE. if i need to use session then first i need to include session using `use Session`, same as for other class `Config`,`Redirect` etc..

Is there any way that i can load all the default functionality in this external class?

Comment: where is your class located? is it somewhere inside App folder?

Comment: D:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\app\MyClasses